# Div Within a Div - Positioned at the Top

Tags: html, css

I am wanting to place a div within another div. The point is to create a border at the top of the div. The border will include a small icon image at the left, and a headline.

I am thinking that there will actually need to be a total of three divs within the main div (lighter grey color). Main border div (100% width...the dark grey color example), then within that div will be two more divs. Div for the small icon (20% width), and a div for the headline content (80% width).

How do you position those three divs (dark grey color), within the main div (lighter grey color) to act like a border at the top? Any short examples would be greatly appreciated.

A link to an example image is provided...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgHk4.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might get you started:

```css
.panel {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: #CCC;
}

.panel header {
  width:100%;
  background-color: #999;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.panel footer {
  font-size: 60%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width:100%;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="panel">
  <header>
    something something
  </header>
  <div class='content'>
    content content
  </div>
  <footer>
    panel footer
  </footer>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```css
.cont {
  width:400px;
  height:500px;
  background: lightgray;
  position: relative;
}

.header {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width:100%;
  height:80px;
  background: gray;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:40px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height:80px;
  padding:0 0px 0 70px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  left:10px;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="header">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/50" alt="">
    HEADLİNE
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="box">
  <h2>
    <span class="box__icon"></span>
    Headline
  </h2>
  <div class="box__content">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OdYaeY

Answer (score 0):

Your thinking is fine, just be sure to use a naming convention that is consistent and works for you.  Here's an example you can feel free to use:

```css
.container { 
  width: 300px; 
  height: 350px;
  margin: 0 auto; 
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana;
  font-size: .95rem;
 }
.header { 
  background: #999; 
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding:.5em;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}
.header .icon {
  display:inline-block;
  min-height: 1rem;
  min-width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.body { 
  background: #ccc; 
  height: 100%; 
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span class="title">headline</span>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    This is your body block
  </div>
</div>
```